# How do you apply a custom font family for placeholder, textbox & button?

Tags: html, css, button, font-face, placeholder

I want to use a custom font from my computer for placeholder and button.

My @font-face.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: customfont2;
        src: url(Font/otf/segment14.regular.otf);
        }
```

I was doing a Dec/Bin/Hex converter

```
 <div id="decimal">
 <input placeholder="Type Decimal Here">
 <button>Convert Decimal</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the question? If it is a problem with seeing the right type face have you used your browser devtools to check that the font is in the right folder?

Comment: I just don't know how to apply custom fonts to buttons, textboxes or placeholders. I want to stylize them a bit. Don't know if I'll use the @font-face above, I just used it as an example. But I don't think I can apply it the same way you can with regular text.

Comment: @a-haworth I fixed the button and textbox text, but what about a different placeholder

Comment: Searching for something like "how to style with css the placeholder in input element" yields good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For button, you just need something like:

```
button{ 
    font-family: customfont2;
}
```

For placeholders, you can try the selectors below:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  font-family: customfont2;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  font-family: customfont2;
}

::placeholder {
  font-family: customfont2;
}
```

More about the [::placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.php) selector

Answer (score 0):

**use input::placeholder**

pseudo element to style placeholder of input element

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mycustomfont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJbecmNE.woff2);
}
 
input,button{
  font-family:'mycustomfont';
}
input::placeholder{
  font-family:'mycustomfont';
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="decimal">
 <input placeholder="Type Decimal Here">
 <button>Convert Decimal</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I figured on my own

```
input[type="text"]
        {
        font-family: customfont4;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        }
input[type="button"]
        {
        font-family: customfont3;
        }
        
button {
font-family: customfont3;
height:28px;
font-size:12pt;
}
::placeholder {
  font-family: customfont2;
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  {
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).